# Discord Bot joins voice channel muted

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am trying to make my discord bot play an MP3 file in a voice channel, however, upon joining the discord bot remains muted, and therefore the audio file isn't audible, even if it may be playing. Here is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} is now running')
    channel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), id=<vc id>)
    voice = await channel.connect()
    source = FFmpegPCMAudio('<filename>.mp3') 
    player = voice.play(source)
```

Does anyone know how to unmute the discord bot?
I'm confident that I've had set the bot permission to be able to speak in voice chats before I invited it to my discord server.

Comment: I can't reproduce this; my test bot connects unmuted by default. I can make it join muted with `channel.connect(self_mute=True)`, but even when muted it *still* plays the audio file in the channel... which might be a bug, frankly.

Comment: Though perhaps you could try `channel.connect(self_mute=False)`? The parameter was [added in version 2.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceProtocol.connect).

Comment: Are you sure you haven't server muted the bot? The mute icon will be red instead of grey.

Comment: No, definitely I've checked everything about the bot, and confirmed that it is not server muted

Comment: @CrazyChucky Also that didnt really work :(

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the bot's log? Have you tried with a different server and/or bot token, to see if the behavior persists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try few things to see the exact issue and fix according to that like:

1. It seems like **discord.FFmpegPCMAudio** is not able to find ffmpeg executable.

```
source = FFmpegPCMAudio('<filename>.mp3', executable='/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg')
```

This `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` should get replaced with yout ffmpeg real path in your linux.

2. In `play` command, you can add after parameter that will takes callback function as its value. This function will be called when the playback is complete or when an error occurs.

You can use this callback function to print out some info about error if it exists:

```
player = voice.play(source, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)
```

3. If the bot is unable to play the audio bcz it's muted, then play will not return an error and callback function passed to `after` parameter  will not be called.

In this, we can see if it's issue with bot's connection to voice channel:
We can check `is_muted()` attribute  of VoiceClient that shows bot connection to the voice channel.

```
if voice.is_muted():
    print("Bot is muted")
```

You have to put after the `voice.play` and check if the bot is muted or not.

> If still this shows muted, then please check your bot permissions overall in discord developer portal & server permissions.

Answer (score -2):

First, `voice.play` is not async. You shouldn't have `await` for [voice.play](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=mute#discord.VoiceClient.play)
Second, don't do so many things in `on_ready` event. Do these by commands (you need to change `discord.Client` to `commands.Bot`. See [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#bot)
Third, if you run this locally, you need to have executable specified in your `FFmpegPCMAudio(executable=..., source=...)`. See [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=voice%20play#ffmpegpcmaudio). Also, you need to install ffmpeg first in order to specify the path.
Fourth, Check your intents, make sure you have `intents.voice_states` enabled. If you already set `Intents.default` or `Intents.all` then you already have the `voice_states`.

Comment: Im on linux, and I have ffmpeg installed. I need the bot to join vc on startup for this specific purpose anyway

Comment: if bot shows a mute sign when joining in vc then checks about intents and channel and category permission for bots (channel permission is higher than the whole server permission)

Answer (score -2):

You need to import discord and specify the client as well as intents for the code to work. You should also replace FFmpegPCMAudio with discord.FFmpegPCMAudio as it's deprecated.

Keep in mind you also need to have discord.py and PyNaCl packages installed.

Here is an example of how your code should look like:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} is now running')
    channel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), id=<vc id>)
    voice = await channel.connect()
    source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('<filename>.mp3')
    voice.play(source)

client.run(TOKEN)
```