# Get bot to unmute self when joining an afk channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I am working on a discord bot for my private server that plays an mp3 file when someone joins the afk channel. The afk channel automatically sets the user to muted when joining, this includes the bot. I am having trouble getting the bot to unmute after joining the channel. The bot has admin permissions so it should be able to unmute its self.

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel and after.channel:
       channel = after.channel
       randomSong= random.choice(os.listdir("file"))
       if channel.id == #id: 
        voice = await channel.connect()
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio(f"{randomSong}")
        voice.play(source )
        print(randomSong)
```

After reading the documentation, connect() can take a self_mute parameter that I set the False but the bot is still muted when it joins the voice channel. I also tried to look up the solution and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75167258/discord-bot-joins-voice-channel-muted) but it didn't really help me.

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel and after.channel:
       channel = after.channel
       randomSong= random.choice(os.listdir("file"))
       if channel.id == #id: 
        voice = await channel.connect(**self_mute=False**)
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio(f"{randomSong}")
        voice.play(source )
        print(randomSong)
```

Comment: You're not giving much information, especially on the part that you've tried. Could you include that explicitly in your question, with the output you got as well (any errors, results, etc...)? What strikes me as odd at first sight is that you're doing `os.listdir("file")`, while `os.listdir` command [expects a folder](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm). Perhaps you can add some logging to your script to show the path of `randomsong` to verify it is what you expect?

Comment: Everything in my code works fine. I am trying to get the bot to unmute itself in the channel it joins. I just changed the the path to "file" for the example code. @SaaruLindestøkke

Comment: Ok, and what about my first point? Can you show in your question what suggestions you have tried [from the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75167258/1256347) and what the outcome was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should say from the start this is not the best way, but this is how I did it:

```py
guild = client.get_guild(server_id)
bot_user = guild.get_member(bot_id)
await bot_user.edit(mute=False)
```

**self_mute** argument only changes the client sides mute. If you join an afk channel, you are server muted instead. You need to get both the server's and the bot's IDs and put them there. Hope this helps!

EDIT:

Instead of `bot_user = guild.get_member(bot_id)` you can use `bot_user = guild.me`

Comment: Thank You for the help, that answered my question and my bot is working now. I would up vote but I do not have a high enough reputation.